# Font size too in first row big for table

Tags: tables, spacing

I'm trying to make a good looking table for my project but when I'm trying to make the font size larger on the first row of the table they get too big and parts of the letters crosses the top line. I would like not to change the size of all of the rows, but only the first. Does anyone know how to do this? The coding is as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|} \hline
\Large{Table} & \Large{Figure} & \Large{Graph} \\ \hline
Good & Bad & Medium \\ \hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert a `\strut` (invisible box) in one of the columns. And, by the way, `\Large` has no argument, it is a switch.

```
        \Large Table & \Large Figure & \Large Graph \strut \\ \hline
```

[image]